# Script for PayPal to action on receipt of money

Tags: paypal, payment

I want to allow access to an article that I have written and is on my website. I have set up an account with PayPal Merchant. I have now got two articles in HTML on my site. One is the full article and the other is an abridged version. The abridged version asks the reader to pay the fee via PayPal. He is taken to PayPal, makes the payment and is then returned to the abridged article. I have a button on the site which loads the unabridged article when pressed.
What I want is for the reader to have access to the unabridged article once he has paid my fee. I would prefer immediate access but it can be after he has returned to the abridged article.
How can I achieve this? I need an appropriate script. 
Any assistance would be gratefully received. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using PayPal "Buy Now" buttons, I would create a return page for each button and place a link to the respective product on the return page. Once the payment is successful the buyer would be redirected to the page with the download link.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for your assistance. You say "Using PayPal "Buy Now" buttons, I would create a return page for each button and place a link to the respective product on the return page". I had done this. But the problem that I now have is that this button to load the unabridged article is always active i.e. the reader/buyer can activate this before or after he has made the payment. I would want this button greyed-out and inactive until the buyer has made the payment. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I did as you suggested. The BuyNow button took the purchaser to PayPal. Once he had paid, Auto Return was supposed to take him back to the unabridged article. However, try as I might, I could not get PayPay to return to the second HTML document i.e. the unabridged article. It always came back to the original document. I had put the address of the second document in Auto Return but to no avail. I then included the address of the second document in replacement coding for the BuyNow button but still no success. I have raised a query with PayPal's technical section and I wait a reply.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I've solved the problem. Auto Return did not work. But altering the coding of the BuyNow button solved the problem.